# Dataframe add column with list of values from groupby

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to generate a list of values, grouped by 'Melder' and add that list as a column to my dataframe. But the apply(list) doesn't work in conjunction with the new_df.insert():

This works, but generates a new Dataframe with only the groupy values

```
new_df2 = new_df.groupby('Melder')['SAG-Nummer'].apply(list)
```

This adds a column to my current dataframe, but the values are all NaN

Example:

```
my_df.insert(1,'Liste',my_df.groupby('Melder')['SAG-ummer'].apply(list))
print(my_df)

      SAG-Nummer Liste   Melder
0  SAG-2001-0389   NaN    Meyer
1  SAG-2001-0388   NaN    Meyer
2  SAG-2001-1833   NaN  Schmidt
3  SAG-2001-1836   NaN     Berg

new_df2 = new_df.groupby('Melder')['SAG-Nummer'].apply(list)
print(my_df2)

Melder
Berg                      [SAG-2001-1836]
Meyer      [SAG-2001-0389, SAG-2001-0388]
Schmidt                   [SAG-2001-1833]
```

Expected Result:

```
      SAG-Nummer Liste                            Melder
0  SAG-2001-0389   [SAG-2001-0389, SAG-2001-0388] Meyer
1  SAG-2001-0388   [SAG-2001-0389, SAG-2001-0388] Meyer
2  SAG-2001-1833   [SAG-2001-1833]                Schmidt
3  SAG-2001-1836   [SAG-2001-1836]                Berg
```

Comment: new_df["new_column"] = new_df.groupby('Melder')['SAG-Number'].transform(len)    maybe like this?

Comment: No, didnt work :(

Comment: @Roland, "but ... with only the groupy values" - but don't you need exactly those values?

Comment: yes, but i want them as a column inside the original dataframe

Comment: post a testable input sample and the expected result

Comment: Edited my question to show the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following transformation to expand the result of each group row-wise:

```
my_df.assign(Liste=my_df.groupby('Melder')['SAG-ummer'].transform(lambda x: [x.values] * len(x)))
```